custom linear interpolation in julia
I'm trying to make the following algorithm more concise:
function tri_linear_interpolation(nx::Int, x::Vector{Float64}, ny::Int, y::Vector{Float64}, nz::Int, z::Vector{Float64}, f::Array{Float64, 3}, xi::Float64, yi::Float64, zi::Float64)
    xlocL = findlast(xx -> xx <= xi, x)
    ylocL = findlast(yy -> yy <= yi, y)
    zlocL = findlast(zz -> zz <= zi, z)

    if xi <= x[1]
        xlocL = 1
    end
    if xlocL >= nx
        xlocL = nx - 1
    end
    if yi <= y[1]
        ylocL = 1
    end
    if ylocL >= ny
        ylocL = ny - 1
    end
    if zi <= z[1]
        zlocL = 1
    end
    if zlocL >= nz
        zlocL = nz - 1
    end

    xL = x[xlocL]
    xH = x[xlocL + 1]
    yL = y[ylocL]
    yH = y[ylocL + 1]
    zL = z[zlocL]
    zH = z[zlocL + 1]

    fLLL = f[xlocL, ylocL, zlocL]
    fLHL = f[xlocL, ylocL + 1, zlocL]
    fHLL = f[xlocL + 1, ylocL, zlocL]
    fHHL = f[xlocL + 1, ylocL + 1, zlocL]

    fLLH = f[xlocL, ylocL, zlocL + 1]
    fLHH = f[xlocL, ylocL + 1, zlocL + 1]
    fHLH = f[xlocL + 1, ylocL, zlocL + 1]
    fHHH = f[xlocL + 1, ylocL + 1, zlocL + 1]

    dxdy = (xH - xL) * (yH - yL)
    fiL = fLLL * (xH - xi) * (yH - yi) / dxdy +
          fHLL * (xi - xL) * (yH - yi) / dxdy +
          fLHL * (xH - xi) * (yi - yL) / dxdy +
          fHHL * (xi - xL) * (yi - yL) / dxdy

    fiH = fLLH * (xH - xi) * (yH - yi) / dxdy +
          fHLH * (xi - xL) * (yH - yi) / dxdy +
          fLHH * (xH - xi) * (yi - yL) / dxdy +
          fHHH * (xi - xL) * (yi - yL) / dxdy

    fi = fiL + (zi - zL) * ((fiH - fiL) / (zH - zL))

    return fi
end

where x, y, and z are sorted vectors. The function should perform linear interpolation of f(x,y,z) at points (xi,yi,zi) and extrapolate out of range.
Here is my attempt:
using Interpolations
function tri_linear_interpolation_concise(x::Vector{Float64}, y::Vector{Float64}, z::Vector{Float64}, f::Array{Float64, 3}, xi::Float64, yi::Float64, zi::Float64)
    # Create an interpolant object with extrapolation handling
    itp = interpolate((x, y, z), f, Gridded(Linear()))
    etp = extrapolate(itp, Linear())
    return etp(xi, yi, zi)
end

This conversion appears to work for most cases, but failed the following test:
x3 = [1.0, 10.0, 100.0, 1000.0]
y3 = [1.0, 10.0, 100.0, 1000.0]
z3 = [1.0, 10.0, 100.0, 1000.0]
f3 = reshape([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0,
              2.0, 4.0, 6.0, 8.0,
              3.0, 6.0, 9.0, 12.0,
              4.0, 8.0, 12.0, 16.0,
              2.0, 4.0, 6.0, 8.0,
              4.0, 8.0, 12.0, 16.0,
              6.0, 12.0, 18.0, 24.0,
              8.0, 16.0, 24.0, 32.0,
              3.0, 6.0, 9.0, 12.0,
              6.0, 12.0, 18.0, 24.0,
              9.0, 18.0, 27.0, 36.0,
              12.0, 24.0, 36.0, 48.0,
              4.0, 8.0, 12.0, 16.0,
              8.0, 16.0, 24.0, 32.0,
              12.0, 24.0, 36.0, 48.0,
              16.0, 32.0, 48.0, 64.0], (4, 4, 4))
xi20, yi20, zi20 = 2000.0, 2000.0, 2000.0
fi20_direct = tri_linear_interpolation(length(x3), x3, length(y3), y3, length(z3), z3, f3, xi20, yi20, zi20)
fi20_concise = tri_linear_interpolation_concise(x3, y3, z3, f3, xi20, yi20, zi20)
@test fi20_direct ≈ fi20_concise

The output for this test is
Evaluated: 133.51989026063097 ≈ 117.33333333333336

Any ideas why this is happening?
Thanks in advance!

I can't immediately tell what's wrong, but I can tell you that your _concise version will be very slow, since you re-compute the entire interpolation object over and over for each output sample. Instead, return etp from the function and use that instead to avoid the unnecessary overhead.
